# Interpreter framework for writing Scheme-like interpreters in < 60 loc

Tags: scheme, interpreter

I wrote [this interpreter](https://github.com/jacktrades/Lispy/tree/master/liSpy) a little while ago and was hoping I could get some comments/criticisms.  It it somewhat similar to the "languages as libraries" concept of Racket, though obviously with less features.

Another goal was to see how little I could implement and still have a usable language.  I chose to implement a Scheme FFI (scheme-syntax ...) that allows defining of primitive syntax forms in the "language layer".

Is this a good/bad approach?  Are there any problems with the implementation in general?  I've never had a code review before and, save for one commenter on Reddit yesterday, I've never had someone read/comment on my code before.

This particular interpreter was written for a [series of blog posts](http://pointlessprogramming.wordpress.com/lispy-in-scheme/) in the style of "An Incremental Approach to Compiler Construction".  It is meant to be as simplistic as possible.  If you want to review that as well I would appreciate it (though don't expect it at all).

```
(use srfi-69)
(use srfi-1)

(define global-syntax-definitions (make-hash-table))
(define-record primitive function)
(define-record proc parameters body environment)

(define (current-environment env) (car env))
(define (enclosing-environment env) (cdr env))

(define (extend-environment bindings base-environment)
  (cons (alist->hash-table bindings) base-environment))

(define the-global-environment (extend-environment '() '()))

(define (set-symbol! symbol value env)
  (hash-table-set! (current-environment env) symbol value))

(define (lookup-symbol-value symbol environment)
  (if (null? environment)
    (conc "Error: Unbound symbol: " symbol)
    (if (hash-table-exists? (current-environment environment) symbol)
        (hash-table-ref (current-environment environment) symbol)
        (lookup-symbol-value symbol (enclosing-environment environment)))))

(define (self-evaluating? expr)
  (or (number? expr) (string? expr) (char? expr) (boolean? expr) (proc? expr)))

(define (lispy-eval expr env)
  (cond ((self-evaluating? expr) expr)
        ((symbol? expr) (lookup-symbol-value expr env))
        (else
          (if (hash-table-exists? global-syntax-definitions (car expr))
              ((hash-table-ref global-syntax-definitions (car expr)) (cdr expr) env)
              (lispy-apply (lispy-eval (car expr) env) (eval-arguments (cdr expr) env))))))

(define (eval-arguments args env)
  (map (lambda (x) (lispy-eval x env)) args))

(define (eval-body args env)
  (last (eval-arguments args env)))

(define (assign-values procedure args)
  (map cons (proc-parameters procedure) args))

(define (lispy-apply procedure arguments) 
  (cond ((primitive? procedure)
           (apply (primitive-function procedure) arguments))
        ((proc? procedure)
           (eval-body (proc-body procedure)
                      (extend-environment (assign-values procedure arguments)
                                          (proc-environment procedure))))
        (else
           (conc "Error: Undefined procedure: " (->string procedure)))))

(hash-table-set! global-syntax-definitions 'scheme-syntax
  (lambda (expr env)
    (hash-table-set! global-syntax-definitions (car expr) (eval (cadr expr)))))

(hash-table-set! global-syntax-definitions 'load
  (lambda (expr env)
    (define f (open-input-file (car expr)))
    (let loop ((e (read f)))
      (if (equal? e #!eof) "Successfully Loaded!"
                           (begin
                             (lispy-eval e env)
                             (loop (read f)))))))

((hash-table-ref global-syntax-definitions 'load) '("scheme_in_lispy.chicken") the-global-environment)

(define (repl)
  (define input (read))
  (print ";===> " (lispy-eval input the-global-environment))
  (repl))

(repl)
```

And here's an example of a very small subset of Scheme implemented in this framework:

```
(scheme-syntax define-primitive
  (lambda (expr env)
    (set-symbol! (car expr)
                 (make-primitive (eval (cadr expr)))
                 env)))

(scheme-syntax define
  (lambda (expr env)
    (if (list? (car expr))
        (set-symbol! (caar expr)
                     (make-proc (cdar expr)
                                (cdr expr)
                                env) env)
        (set-symbol! (car expr) (lispy-eval (cadr expr) env) env))))

(scheme-syntax lambda
  (lambda (expr env)
    (make-proc (car expr)
               (cdr expr)
               env)))

(scheme-syntax if
  (lambda (expr env)
    (if (lispy-eval (car expr) env)
        (lispy-eval (cadr expr) env)
        (lispy-eval (caddr expr) env))))

(scheme-syntax quote
  (lambda (expr env)
    (car expr)))

(scheme-syntax set!
  (lambda (expr env)
    (set-symbol! (car expr) (lispy-eval (cadr expr) env) env)))

(scheme-syntax begin
  (lambda (expr env)
    (eval-body expr env)))

(scheme-syntax let
  (lambda (expr env)
    (eval-body (cdr expr) (extend-environment (car expr) env))))

(scheme-syntax equal?
  (lambda (expr env)
    (equal? (lispy-eval (car expr) env)
            (lispy-eval (cadr expr) env))))

(define-primitive + +)
(define-primitive - -)
(define-primitive < <)
(define-primitive > >)
(define-primitive car car)
(define-primitive cdr cdr)
(define-primitive cons cons)
(define-primitive print print)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a hidden bug in the interpreter.

Your `eval-body` calls `eval-arguments` to evaluate the body expressions of a compound procedure, but the evaluation order of `map` it not defined in Scheme. The procedure bodies should be evaluated with `for-each` as it has well-defined evaluation order from left to right. Both the following are correct implementations of Scheme `map` (for simplicity, shown with unary function arguments only):

```
  (define (map f ls) ;; evaluates in left-to-right order
    (if (null? ls) '()
        (let ((val (f (car ls))))
          (cons val (map f (cdr ls))))))

  (define (map f ls) ;; evaluates in right-to-left order
    (if (null? ls) '()
        (let ((rs (map f (cdr ls))))
          (cons (f (car ls)) rs))))
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  That was the result of oversimplifying this:
`(define (eval-arguments exps env)
  (if (null? exps)
      '()
      (cons (meta-eval (car exps) env)
            (eval-arguments (cdr exps) env))))`
I'll look into using for-each.  I've never used it before and this seems as good an excuse as any.

Comment: Yes, `for-each` is like `map` but used when you evaluate the expression for their side-effects instead of their values; because of this emphasis, `for-each` has a well-defined execution order.